# Linux LowFree and Slab

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

Currently, My Router ran into a weired situation which the MemoryFree keeps growing down, but with no one growing up while searching the /proc/meminfo! How could this happen?

At the very beginning:

```
MemTotal:         513112 kB
MemFree:          453244 kB
MemAvailable:     397132 kB
Buffers:            3664 kB
Cached:            11428 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            10476 kB
Inactive:           8036 kB
Active(anon):       3512 kB
Inactive(anon):     1024 kB
Active(file):       6964 kB
Inactive(file):     7012 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:         65536 kB
HighFree:          62968 kB
LowTotal:         447576 kB
LowFree:          390276 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          3552 kB
Mapped:             3016 kB
Shmem:              1116 kB
Slab:              15412 kB
SReclaimable:       2952 kB
SUnreclaim:        12460 kB
KernelStack:         632 kB
PageTables:          396 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      256556 kB
Committed_AS:      14288 kB
VmallocTotal:    1015800 kB
VmallocUsed:        7816 kB
VmallocChunk:     990320 kB
```

After some days:

```
MemTotal:         513112 kB
MemFree:          298280 kB
MemAvailable:     241060 kB
Buffers:            3068 kB 
Cached:            10700 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:            11084 kB
Inactive:           6284 kB
Active(anon):       4112 kB
Inactive(anon):     1180 kB
Active(file):       6972 kB
Inactive(file):     5104 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
HighTotal:         65536 kB
HighFree:          62164 kB
LowTotal:         447576 kB
LowFree:          236116 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                 0 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:          3644 kB
Mapped:             3064 kB
Shmem:              1692 kB
Slab:              17224 kB
SReclaimable:       2632 kB
SUnreclaim:        14592 kB
KernelStack:         576 kB
PageTables:          392 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      256556 kB
Committed_AS:      14904 kB
VmallocTotal:    1015800 kB
VmallocUsed:        7656 kB
VmallocChunk:     952764 kB
```

Since the SLAB area does not significant changed, so the leaks must not be leaked by the kmalloc/kfree API and their companions(LowFree is growing down, so the leak must be laying somewhere in the kernelspace). Can anybody help me?
Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found that the Leak was caused by the MTK WIFI driver, which called dev_alloc_skb to allocate an skb and forget to free it.
The dev_alloc_skb internally allocated the skb->data via alloc_pages directly and it not be recorded by the slab.